# Como pegar apenas o valor de uma coluna no banco de dados

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso pegar todos os registro de apenas uma coluna no banco de dados, e estou fazendo assim:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT link FROM conteudo WHERE status = 'false'")

reviewlinks = mycursor.fetchall()
```

E ele funciona, exceto que o resultado vem dentro de (), por exemplo:

```
[('https://10reviewz.com/best-step-ladder-wirecutter/',), ('https://10reviewz.com/best-magnetic-stirrer-for-e-juice/',), ('https://10reviewz.com/best-luggage-cart-for-car-seat/',), ('https://10reviewz.com/best-marine-barometers/',), ('https://10reviewz.com/best-smart-scales-for-apple/',), ('https://10reviewz.com/best-golf-putters-for-alignment/',)]
```

Não entendo pq ele está retornando dessa maneira, pois preciso retornar apenas os links dentro do array, mas ele coloca o link dentro de () e ainda poem uma vírgula no final.

Pq isso está acontecendo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A definição do método fetchall](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) é a seguinte:

> O método busca todas (ou todas remanescentes) linhas do resultado de uma query e retorna uma **lista de tuplas**...

Haja visto que cada linha retornada pode ter mais que um campo, a vírgula do próximo elemento da [tupla](https://blog.betrybe.com/tecnologia/tuplas-em-python/) permanece ali mesmo que não exista (já que o conceito deste tipo de estrutura é justamente a imutabilidade).

Tendo isso em vista, considerando que cada linha retornará apenas um campo (`link`), você pode armazenar o primeiro valor de cada tupla (que será o link) em uma nova lista:

```py
new_result = [f[0] for f in result]
print(new_result)

# ['https://10reviewz.com/best-step-ladder-wirecutter/',
# 'https://10reviewz.com/best-magnetic-stirrer-for-e-juice/',
# ...]
```

Comment: muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento e ajuda. (Y)